# How to run the script once at resize?

Tags: javascript

Suppose there are points for mob, tab and desk.
`mob is "<768"`
`tab is "> = 768" and "<1024"`
`desk is "> 1024"`

It turns out when you reach the tab, you need to perform the function once, if the window has changed and become a mob, again you need to execute the function once, etc.

I did so

```
$(function() {
  var isDevice = "mob"; /* mob tab desk */

  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth < 768) {
      if (isDevice != "mob") {
        isDevice = "mob";
        console.log(isDevice);
      }
    } else if (windowWidth >= 768 && windowWidth < 1024) {
      if (isDevice != "tab") {
        isDevice = "tab";
        console.log(isDevice);
      }
    } else if (windowWidth >= 1024) {
      if (isDevice != "desk") {
        isDevice = "desk";
        console.log(isDevice);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This works as expected, but maybe there is a better way to implement it?

link to [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/inkshio/pen/PrdybR).

Comment: How is this related to `react.js`?

Comment: Good material for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var isDevice = "mob" /* mob tab desk */
  var doit;
  window.onresize = function(){
    clearTimeout(doit);
    doit = setTimeout(resizedw, 500);
  };   
});

function resizedw(){

 var windowWidth = $(window).width();
 //Implement logic here
    

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```